# jquery how to capture value after event

Tags: jquery, callback, eventtrigger

I have made tremendous progress with my coding and only have 1 final question left. How can I capture the value of another textbox in a partialview and transfer it to my current textbox. This is the simple code

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#form0').trigger('submit',function()
            {
              $("#longituder").val() = $("#sese").val();
            });


        });
</script>
```

The form0 has the textbox with i.d. **#sese** and it always has a value, I am trying to get that value into my textbox of **#longituder** . This needs to be a callback function as by the time the DOM finishes textbox **#sese** won't be found since its inside of the trigger event and takes a few seconds afterwards to come into the page; is there some form in which I can delay this section

```
$("#longituder").val() = $("#sese").val();
```

until the .trigger has ran?

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect

```
 $("#longituder").val() = $("#sese").val();
```

Should be

```
 $("#longituder").val($("#sese").val());
```

With delay:

```
 $("#longituder").delay(2000).val($("#sese").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

First

- you need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register an event handler, [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) is used to trigger an event
- to assign a value, you need to use the [setter version](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) of [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form0').on('submit', function () {
        $("#longituder").val($("#sese").val());
    });
});
```